# How can I pass StatefulWidget's constuctor argument to State?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cywpL.png)

How can i assign final String blog_id; value that we get from const KidneyDiseaseBody({Key? key, required this.blog_id}) : super(key: key); in String query = ; in class _KidneyDiseaseBodyState

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620675/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  query = widget.blog_id; // or whatever way you want to use it
}
```

you cannot do

```
  String query = widget.blog_id;
```

since widget is assigned after State is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as `widget.blog_id`.

Comment: But not during construction, because the state's widget field is not assigned until afterwards. Use initState() as advised in Gazihan Alankus' answer.