# How to open Dropdown menu from other widget when ontap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the dropdown menu and it works fine, all I want is how can I open this menu from somewhere else. I have the global key but I couldn't find how to do it. I examined the previously opened posts, the codes there did not work on my computer.

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              key: dropdownKey,
              value: e.feedback,
              isExpanded: true,

              hint: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text("Seçiniz",
                      style: ThemeText.orderDetailTitle
                          .copyWith(color: Color(0xFFA2ADB8)))),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                color: Color(0xFFA2ADB8),
              ),
              iconSize: 25,
              underline: SizedBox(),
              onChanged: (value) async {
              },
              items: e.didBought == true
                  ? _dropdownBoughtReasonsItems
                  : _dropdownReturnReasonsItems,
      
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Have you checked this discussion ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620675/13997210) hope its help to you. just declare your dropdown widget same as mobilegraph() widget

Comment: @esentis yes, i saw that post and i couldn't get it to work

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil This is not what I mean, what I want is, I want to open the list that opens when I click on dropdown, in the same way by clicking somewhere else.